# Making a Kibana plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, kibana, kibana-4

I've made chart in javascript language that don't need a elasticsearch data to work. I want to put this chart as a plugin to Kibana. My plugin structure is like:

`index.html

files/mychart.js

files/mychart.css`

and a few more js and css (like jquery,dragdealer etc.)

To run this chart in browser You use index.html. Is there a simple way to put this chart into Kibana as a plugin? I want to put my chart into Kibana dashboard that’s why I need to make a plugin. I read https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-simple-visualizations/ tutorial but I'm not sure if the solution which was shown there is a proper one for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is a plugin that supports html. Maybe you could just drop your code into that plugin - without having to create a new one. https://github.com/raystorm-place/kibana-html-plugin

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply I need to put all js into my html directly, but this plugin helps a lot! I think this is it! :)